# Removing padding from Outlook 2007, 2010, and 2013 when applying background color in body

Tags: html, html-email, outlook-2007, outlook-2010

After stackoverflowing and googling, I can't remove this padding in Outlook 2007, Outlook 2010, and Outlook 2013. Note: I use table layout for this build.

Note: I already used this:

```
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;" bgcolor="#00a3ad">
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a bunch of stuff in the [HTML Boilerplate](http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/) that could be related, so try putting these in your style tag:

```
html {width: 100%;} 
body {width:100% !important;}
.ReadMsgBody, .ExternalClass {width:100%; display:block !important;}
table td {border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;} 
#backgroundTable {margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important;} 
p.MsoNormal {margin: 0px}
```

I always put this stuff in the head of each email, so I'm not exactly sure if any or all will make a difference in your case, but I'd suggest always putting at least some of the HTML Boilerplate CSS in there to normalize the code on every email.

Other than that, try adding 'px' to your 0 values (stupid I know but email is like that sometimes), or take a look at any nested table, making sure it is set to 100% with cellpadding="0" and cellspacing="0".

Hopefully something there gets the job done.

Comment: Thanks anyway, John. I do have all the staff and I already tried all of these options. I just really doubt if there is anyway to remove this generic padding in Outlook

Comment: On second look, I just spotted the difference between the two images (must have been still half asleep) If you want to get rid of the cyan on the sides of your white panel, I'd suggest using a 100% width background table and applying the bgcolor there instead of coloring the body tag. This technique also stops the background color bleeding into the forwarded section if the recipient forwards the email (otherwise they'd be typing on cyan, not white).

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party but I've just been working through this problem myself and have a 'fix' written up here: http://theboywhocriedfox.com/code-snippets/fixing-the-forced-body-padding-in-outlook-2007-2010-and-2013/

In short you need to add negative margin to the outer table for just the offending clients.

Comment: This will not work now they have dropped support for margin completely